# Scroll time increment effect on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll

I am working on a project using ElasticSearch and querying it to fetch the member information. It has 3 million records.

I am running a campaign for 2 million users and the user data is present on **elasticsearch6.2**. I query the ES and fetches the records in batches (50 records at a time) using the **scroll**. Also, I want to keep the **SEARCH context for 1 day** because if the campaign running process fails due to any reason, I can resume the campaign from where it was stopped. In this way, I will escape from starting the campaign again from starting. I am also saving the **scrollID**  and will use it to resume campaign.

While testing I found CPU Utilization increased by 50% (ES config: 2 nodes with 4 shards running on aws, Instance Type:**i3.xlarge.elasticsearch**) and its CPU Utilization remains consistent to 50%.

Is there any relation between CPU Utilization and keeping the search context for 1day. BTW campaigns take 6 hours to finish.

Comment: Please do not use Indian words here. Other people will not understand what are "lakh records", let alone "L"

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)

> Normally, the background merge process optimizes the index by merging
>   together smaller segments to create new bigger segments, at which time
>   the smaller segments are deleted. This process continues during
>   scrolling, but an open search context prevents the old segments from
>   being deleted while they are still in use. This is how Elasticsearch
>   is able to return the results of the initial search request,
>   regardless of subsequent changes to documents.

So with your scroll cursor expiration to 24h it seems you forbid Lucene to merge your segments, increasing to load of your shards.

Later in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api) there is an explanation on how to clear your scroll cursor :

> Search context are automatically removed when the scroll timeout has
>   been exceeded. However keeping scrolls open has a cost, as discussed
>   in the previous section so scrolls should be explicitly cleared as
>   soon as the scroll is not being used anymore using the clear-scroll
>   API:

You should try to clear your cursor after a campaign is completed.